# Best Opensource Online Task Management/Project manager?

Tags: open-source, project-management, taskmanager

Best Online Open source Project manager/Task Manager???

Comment: AFAIK, there are not many open source apps that are online as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out 37signals apps like [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/). They have free plans.

Answer (score 4):

I'm Using [collabtive](http://www.collabtive.com/)

Comment: Unable to Download it any alternative link other then SourceForgue?

Comment: That's the only link to download.

Comment: Collabtive is the best if you want to manage your own system of using the one of other...

Comment: I use collabtive too but it must be improved. There should be self hosted alternatives to it :( .... anyway it's the best option for now it seems

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Teamlab](http://teamlab.com) it's free and open source

Answer (score 2):

Been quite impressed by [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) myself.
There are [hosting providers](http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/2790).

Answer (score 2):

I discovered [Plancake](http://www.plancake.com/). It looks pretty neat.